# Telegram RPC request to destroy specific session

Tags: api, telegram

Which is the right RPC in the [current Layer 54](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl) in order to destroy a telegram session?

I've tried the:

```
    destroy_session#e7512126 session_id:long = DestroySessionRes;
```

Which should answer with:

```
    destroy_session_ok#e22045fc session_id:long = DestroySessionRes;
    destroy_session_none#62d350c9 session_id:long = DestroySessionRes;
```

But or I am doing something wrong, or it isn't the right way to do this.

Comment: what response are you getting?

Comment: Hey Charles! Seems no answer at all...

Comment: are you able to receive responses to other requests?

Comment: yes, other rpc answers correctly. Is this RPC the only things I need to destroy the session of a connected client? Because if yes, I should investigate if something is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
destroy_session#e7512126 session_id:long = DestroySessionRes;
```

Make sure you use the correct `sessionid`, clearly not from within the same current session

To destroy the current session, you can simply do it from your Phone:

On Android:

```
Settings > Privacy and Security > Active Sessions - Tap on a session to terminate
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to destroy the current session?

Comment: Also: what is the correct RPC to remove an user from a chat?
Is the messages.deleteChatUser#e0611f16 chat_id:int user_id:InputUser = Updates; with InputUser = InputUserSelf the correct way to remove myself from a group?

Comment: Kindly post those comments in a separate question. By the way, most of these functions follow their names if you look @ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl